# How to reload collectionView - Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments Error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Ok, I'm a noob and already looked all over the web for a few days now. But I also almost pulled all my hair out of my head.

I'm making an photo-upload app. And using CollectionView to make a photo grid.
I managed to code the "pick a photo from foto library" but It doesn't display my foto.

The build error I get is: **Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments Error**.
for the: **collectionView.reloadData()**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var tableImages = [UIImage]()

var uploadButtonVisible = false

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    println("Image selected")
    println ("imagename= \(image)")


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    tableImages.append(image)
    println("\(tableImages)")

    collectionView.reloadData()

}


func uploadButtonOn(){
    println("Button Activated!")

    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(image, animated: false, completion: nil)


}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    println(tableImages.count)

    // append an uploadbutton if photo limit not reached
    if tableImages.count <= 6 {

        tableImages += [UIImage(named: "button.jpg")!]

    }

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    println("tableImages.count is: \(tableImages.count)")
    return tableImages.count


}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.cellImage.image = tableImages[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("cell \(indexPath.row) selected")


    if indexPath.row == (tableImages.count - 1) {

        uploadButtonVisible = true

        if uploadButtonVisible {
            uploadButtonOn()
        }


    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image: CollectionViewCell file]
[image: My app file structure]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks =)

Comment: Isn't collectionview an optional? did you try collectionView?.reloadData()

Comment: yes @IcaroNZ I tried it but got the same result.

Comment: The lines you are printing in the console show that the image was successfully load into your image array?

Comment: Correct @IcaroNZ I get the array with images:   
imagename= <UIImage: 0x7faa607c6fa0> size {1500, 1001} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
[<UIImage: 0x7faa61904ae0> size {1600, 1067} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, <UIImage: 0x7faa607c6fa0> size {1500, 1001} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
performBatchUpdates
```

?

I had issues with the various grid refresh methods several months back (in ObjectiveC, though). I looked back at my code and found that I used a mix of performBatchUpdates and reloadData. I cannot remember exactly what the reason was, but it does not hurt to try the other method if it exists in Swift.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement this?
I found o bit about it arround, but do not know how to implement it.

Comment: It just a method on the grid that you can call instead of reloadData.